# Celery and oslo config not working together

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, celery, openstack

What is the best way to initialize oslo.cfg in a celery project ?

I want to do this:

```
from phantom.openstack.common import cfg

import os

possible_topdir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__),
                                   os.pardir, os.pardir))
conf_file = os.path.join(possible_topdir, 'etc/phantom', 'phantom.conf')
print 'config done 1'
config_files = None
if os.path.exists(conf_file):
    config_files = [conf_file]
print 'config done 2'
cfg.CONF(project='phantom', default_config_files=[conf_file])
```

I have my config file where I store a set of URLs and user privileges that I would use to access different systems during different task executions.

I tried setting it up in my celery.py where I have this right now

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery(include=['phantom.tasks.celery_tasks'])
celery.config_from_object('bin.celeryconfig')
```

If I insert it into this block, it gives me back an error saying:

```
LM-SJN-00871893:Phantom uruddarraju$ celery -A phantom.celery.celery worker -l DEBUG

usage: celery [-h] [--version] [--config-file PATH] [--config-dir DIR]
celery: error: unrecognized arguments: -A phantom.celery.celery worker -l DEBUG
```